# Look at the following infinite sequence: 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, . . ..

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the proof that there are 2 numbers in this sequence that differ by a multiple of 12345678987654321?

Comment: I think it is true. There are precisely $12345678987654321$ residue classes modulo $12345678987654321$. Now use the pigeon hole principle.

Comment: Fun fact: $12345678987654321 = 111111111^2 = (3^2 \cdot 37\cdot 333667)^2$

Comment: So can this notion be generalized? In what way? Does the series or the number has a special property? Or their relation is somewhat special?

Comment: @Olcayto: Yes, greatly. You can replace 'powers of 10' with 'powers of $n$' for any integer $n$, and replace 12345678987654321 with any nonzero integer.

Comment: You can replace 'powers of $10$' with any integer sequence you'd like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n = 12345678987654321$.  Consider the first $n+1$ elements of the powers-of-10 sequenc modulo $n$.  According to the pigeonhole principle,  there are at least two of these elements that have the same residue modulo $n$.  Their difference is a multiple of $n$.

Comment: This is beautifully applied pigeonhole, and not what I expected on a post like this, but it works so well.

Comment: So this can be generalized for any number and any geometric sequence.

Comment: @Olcayto‌: Any number and _any_ sequence. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I think it's implied here that while a difference of  0 is technically a multiple of any number, it's not an acceptable answer.  So any sequence without duplicates would work.

Answer (score 1):

call your number $n.$ Note that it is not divisible by $2$ or $5.$ So $\gcd(10,n) = 1.$ By http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem  we have
$$ 10^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \equiv 10^{0} \pmod n.  $$

Answer (score -2):

Take the digit 1 from the 10 and take the digit 1 from the 100.  They differ by 0 which is a multiple of 12345678987654321.